# Python 3 kivy ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu, kivy

I have a simple python kivy source code (only a example) and I execute the code in virtuelenv. The "program" runs without errors.
But unfortunately I see not the open window - only the Python Icon on the bottom from my task bar.
What I have to do that the windows opens?

```
# Datei: hello.py

import kivy
kivy.require('1.9.0') # Mindest-Version von Kivy

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button


class HelloApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return Button(text='Hallo Welt!')

if __name__== "__main__":
    HelloApp().run()
```

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Z5tU.png)

Comment: If you use the example in the docs, does that show a window? https://kivy.org/doc/stable/gettingstarted/first_app.html#

Comment: I run the python code on my terminal:  python3 hello.py.